# Need an Expressjs-nodejs-mongoose tutorial to build a simple RESTful service

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Being fairly new to nodejs and mongoDB,
I have looked up all over the net to get a tutorial where express is used with node and mongoose.
What I need is express's route feature to detect requests and perform database operations accordingly.

I do not need jade or any other templates , I just plan to return a json structure read from monogDB/mongoose on an express route request.

A simple **server.js** file would suffice where a single express route is provided with interaction using mongoose to a mongodb database.

I suppose this is quiet simple while speaking but its really difficult to put these pieces together when one doesnt know much about node / mongo / mongoose. and the examples available on the net are overkill.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should behave more responsibly by first searching and putting your efforts.

This is a very detailed tutorial about the same requirements,

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

But please be more responsible to the community in future.